# Which cryptographic algorithm is this?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I am investigating a custom network protocol which i believe has som sort of data encryption.

The following happens when a client connects to a server:

```
Client --- [128 bit  random  key] --> Server
Client <-- [128 bit  random  key] --- Server
Client --- [128 bit (random) key] --> Server
Client <-- [128 bit (random) key] --- Server

Data sent and received is encrypted from now on.
```

I would like to know what kind of cryptographic implementation i am dealing with.

Comment: It looks like the two way SSL handshake -> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Ssl_handshake_with_two_way_authentication_with_certificates.png.

Comment: How can you make the difference between the **random** keys exchanges and the encrypted data (which will look **random**) ? You might want to try if a tool, like `wireshark`, is able to detect the protocol being used.

Comment: I am in control of the server side so i can change the keys sent by the server so they will be not so random at all, for example: 128 x 0x00. but when i do this, the keys sent by the client will still be random.

Comment: It could be a Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: The information given is not enough to provide a full answer, although the SSL handshake seems to be the most viable option.

Comment: So these four messages can be a complete SSL handshake? isn't there suppose to be something like a client/server hello message, exchange of cipher suites? and does a certificate fits in a 128 byte message?

Comment: This **cannot** be SSL or any kind of Diffie-Hellman. 128 bit messages are way too small for anything but some kind of symmetric key exchange.

Comment: Is it possible use DLL injection to find out what cryptography methods are being called? for instance the Windows Crypto API, crypt32.dll...

Comment: Could it be some sort of XOR encryption? because the encrypted data seems to have the same length as the non-encrypted data -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

Comment: @HenrickHellström good point, I was thinking 128 byte, which would point to an asymmetric algorithm. As said, we can only guess because of the amount of info given. Modding down because no response and not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your post to answer this question. All you know is that there is some kind of exchange of information taking place in blocks of 128bits.

People here will inevitably post a series of algorithms that this is *not* (for instance, it's not SSL or a normal DH exchange), but without the contents of the bytes, it's not possible to say for sure what algorithm this *is*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is pure for learning purposes and I was hoping someone could give me a hint of what this possibly could be, I was not looking for the correct answer in the first place. I'm still on this so if I can get any further I'l post the answer myself.